# Why are my images blurry on React Native Image component and how can I fix it?

Tags: javascript, react-native, tailwind-css

I am developing a mobile travel application and for my home screen I tried to get a an image for background but my image is getting blurry. [This is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axEj8.jpg). [This is the intended image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1D3i.jpg).

I tried using resizeMode without any effect. I tried changing the width and height it did nothing. I also tried changing  with flexbos but without any help. This is what my code looks like. I want to say that I am beginner with react native and flexbox. Any tips and helps is more than welcome. Have a great day.

````
<SafeAreaView className="flex-1">
      {/* Image section */}
      <View className="flex-1 justify-center items-center">
        <Image source={TM2} className=" flex -1 w-[100%] h-[100%]" />
      </View>
      <View className=" absolute align-middle justify-center items-center mt-[30%] ml-[25%]">
        <Text className="text-[#eeeaea] text-[40px] font-bold tracking-wide">
          Explore
        </Text>
        <View className="align-middle justify-center items-center ">
          <Text className="text-[#eeeaea] text-[20px] font-semibold tracking-wide">
            the journey
          </Text>
        </View>
      </View>```
````

Comment: This could be the expected behaviour because your screenshot has a height resolution of 2048px and your image has only 295px. You either need a higher resolution image or a smaller container for the image. Assuming you want the image to be full screen you will have to find a bigger image. Also keep in mind the aspect ration - portrait vs landscape.